# How to move transform.y according to NGUI Slider value in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game where I have to pick some objects with fork lifter I write this code to do this but it is not working properly. not going to desired point after the object is picked...

```
public UISlider Slider;
public GameObject Lifter;
public float temp;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    temp = Slider.GetComponent<UISlider> ().value;
    if (Slider.GetComponent<UISlider> ().value == 0) {
        Lifter.transform.position = new Vector3 (Lifter.transform.position.x, transform.position.y + temp - 1.2f, Lifter.transform.position.z);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Lifter.transform.position = new Vector3 (Lifter.transform.position.x, 0.39, Lifter.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the slider value only when slider value is 0, which is not right. Try using this code -

```
public Slider MySlider;
public GameObject Lifter;
public float temp;

private float LifterInitialY = 0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    LifterInitialY = Lifter.transform.position.y;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Lifter.transform.position = new Vector3 (Lifter.transform.position.x, LifterInitialY + MySlider.value , Lifter.transform.position.z);
}
```

EDIT: to move the fork upward(Y-axis) when slider value becomes 1 -

Add a variable for measured value -

```
...
private float LifterInitialY = 0f;
private float someMeasuredValue = 0f;
...
```

And add a check for slider value in `Update` method -

```
void Update () {
    if(MySlider.value >= 1f){
        someMeasuredValue = 1.2f; // measure some value
    }else{
        someMeasuredValue = 0f;
    }
    Lifter.transform.position = new Vector3 (Lifter.transform.position.x, LifterInitialY + MySlider.value + someMeasuredValue , Lifter.transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: ths code is working but not properly because when the value of the slider will be 1 fork has to transform some measured value

Comment: You can add check for slider value 1 as `if(MySlider.value == 1f){//do something}`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "fork has to transform some measured value"?

Comment: measured value means fork has to transform upward after picking some object at some level where drive can see front view properly